# Changing the value of a variable php

Tags: php, forms, validation, variables

I need to change the value of the variable `$destination` to help validate a form. If none of the fields within the form, the page refreshes with the error message displayed, which works. If the fields are all filled in, the the `$destination` value should change and the message `'it works!'` is printed. However, if all fields are filled in and the user submits the form, the message `'it works!'` is printed, but the `$destination`'s value is still set to `'this-page'`. What am I missing here?

```
$destination = '';

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if (!$fname OR !$lname OR !$email OR !$phone) {
print 'Please fill in all of your contact information';
$destination = 'this-page';
}
else {
print 'It works!';
    $destination = 'results-page';
}
```

Comment: use isset, if isset($fname), etc...

Comment: If you need all rows aren't empty i recomend you to use && (and) not OR. And use the recomendation of fellows answers

Comment: somehow I knew that the question answer would not be accepted...

Answer (score 0):

```
$destination = '';

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if (!empty($fname) || !empty($lname) || !empty($email) OR !empty($phone)) {
    print 'Please fill in all of your contact information';
    $destination = 'this-page';
}
else {
    print 'It works!';
    $destination = 'results-page';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is academic.  There are better ways to approach this.  But here:

```
$destination = '';

$fname = isset($_POST['fname']) ? $_POST['fname'] : null ;
$lname = isset($_POST['lname']) ? $_POST['lname'] : null ;
$phone = isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : null ;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null ;

if (empty($fname) || empty($lname) || empty($phone) || empty($email)) {
    print 'Please fill in all of your contact information';
    $destination = 'this-page';
} else {
    print 'It works!';
    $destination = 'results-page';
}
```

Someday take a look at some PHP frameworks and how they handle form validation.  for example: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.elements.html  Might give you some insight.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problems isn't related to the validation part here. You are getting both the print from the else statement and the $destination variable from the if statement? That should  be logically impossible. Are you sure you don't have any syntax errors etc. in your code? Is that the exact code you have in your program?